# M2Mqtt library with HiveMQ

Tags: c#, ssl, mosquitto, hivemq

So i have a hivemq server running on my local machine and I'm trying to get it to where I can connect to the server using the M2Mqtt library in c# over TLS. I followed this guide to create the certs for c#.

http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/PaoloPatierno/tabid/106/entryid/366/MQTT-over-SSL-TLS-with-the-M2Mqtt-library-and-the-Mosquitto-broker.aspx

then i followed this guide to convert the certs to jks keystores for hivemq.
http://blog.jgc.org/2011/06/importing-existing-ssl-keycertificate.html

I verified the certs and code to be working using mosquitomq just like the first guide did. I assume its how the jks keystores are made, but if anyone has any information on this please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the password of your keypair is the same as the password of the keystore

see http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/2.0.0/#ssl-configuration-chapter

there is also a nice explanation with images on how to create a keystore
http://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/2.0.0/#hivemqdocs_howto_configure_ssl_with_hivemq_and_keytool